# Why am I getting 404 error on this URL https://davedevzone.com/chat/ and not directly from port https://davedevzone.com:3001

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

Hi I'm having trouble setting up the path of a nodejs app but I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I configured nginx or the way I'm setting up my application.

Basically I want to serve the following: https://davedevzone.com:3001/

as a nice formated url without the port, like this: https://davedevzone.com/chat/

However, when I try to go to that last url, as you can see it crashes with 404 errors on every resource it tries to load (css files and js files)

I've noticed that if I replace the local path for each resource tag with the full url including the port it solves the issue. For example:

https://davedevzone.com:3001/css/site.css

loads fine. But I'm not sure if this is the proper way to things or if it will bring me any complications in the future. For me it feels like the easy way out and that's usually never good in my experience.

Here's the full code of my app:

**index.js (server side)**

```
var port = 3001; // app's port
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//var http = require('http').Server(app);
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem')
},app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.use('/css', express.static('css'));
app.use('/js', express.static('js'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});


server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

**index.html (client)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/site.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        $('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var msg = $('#m').val();
            socket.emit('chat message', msg);
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });

        console.log("from nodeprojects folder");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my **nginx config file** from /etc/nginx/sites-available/davedevzone.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.html index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name davedevzone.com www.davedevzone.com;

    location /sample/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }

    location /chat/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3001/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    } 


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/davedevzone.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/davedevzone.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: If you omit a port number from a URL, the URL's scheme component dictates the port used. For HTTPS, that means port 443. If the server is running on a different port, you simply cannot omit the port from the URL. No amount of server side scripting can change that, since clients (like browsers) will try to connect to the port that the URL specifies/implies.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/site.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/chat/css/site.css" />
```

And do the same for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and `/js/jquery-1.11.1.js`.
Then it requests them from the chat URL which is reverse proxied to port 3001.

Comment: This almost works, now it appears that socket.io can't connect(?). I'm getting the following error in client side: /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ma1QlbP:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).                                     Oh and by the way, this screws up the one that was already working: https://davedevzone.com:3001

Comment: Cant't see that error. Change your code so I can see the error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've just changed the code and restarted the app. https://davedevzone.com:3001/ https://davedevzone.com/chat/

Comment: Change `var socket = io();` 
to
`var socket = io('https://davedevzone.com', {
  path: '/chat/socket.io'
});
` in the HTML

Comment: it works but.... https://davedevzone.com:3001/  no longer works :/  is kinda like trading one for the other. Sigh... I thought this proxy thing would be so much easier.